# Terminal velocity proof

Tags: calculus

How do we integrate:

$\int^v_0 \frac {dv_y}{v_y  - v_t}$, where $v_y$ is vertical acceleration at a certain time and $v_t$ is terminal velocity, a given constant. In particular, I am stuck at $ln(0)$ in the denominator.

This is for the LHS of Newton's second law. I don't remember the diff-e-q process involved.

We should get $ ln \frac {v_t - v_y}{v_t}$?

Comment: The antiderivative of $\frac{1}{v_y-v_t}$ with respect to $v_y$ is $\ln|v_y-v_t|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^\nu \frac{d\nu _y}{\nu_y-\nu_t}=\left. \ln\left| \nu_y-\nu_t\right| \right|_0^{\nu} = \ln\left| \nu-\nu_t\right|-\ln\left|\nu_t\right| = \ln\left| \frac{\nu-\nu_t}{\nu_t}\right|$$

Comment: Thanks I don't know why I deluded myself into thinking ln(v_t) is 0.

Comment: @MathNewbie MY pleasure. These things happen from time to time. Notation can throw you off. I'd appreciate if you would accept the answer :)